# Spring Boot logging with logback

Tags: spring-boot, logback

What I'd like to do is to keep `logback.xml` file out of my war file deployed to tomcat. So I am passing system variable `-Dlogging.config` pointing to absolute path to `logback.xml`.

Spring boot intercepts this system variable in `application.propeties` (located on classpath) in this way `logging.config=file:${logging.config}` (it's the only content of this file). And the partial contents of `logback.xml` looks like:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>C:/Users/user/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

The solution works in tomcat 8 deployed on Windows but it doesn't work on Tomcat 8 deployed on linux (the logs folder is empty). I adjusted values accordingly to Linux environemnt:                             `-Dlogging.config=/home/tomcat/config/logback.xml`  and in `logback.xml`:

```
  <fileNamePattern>/home/tomcat/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work on Linux side?

Comment: First - check Spring Boot start-up console messages for warnings/errors - there should be a hint if logback initializes properly or not. Double check your paths. Check permissions on the folders you're trying to write to. If nothing works, just for a test run, try to put configs and write locations in folders which are in the directory-tree structure _below_ the initialization directory of the class loader.

Comment: Try `-DLOGGING_CONFIG` instead.

Comment: It turned out to be a mistake in logback.xml path.